# Destructuring an array of objects (es6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm wondering how to destructure an array of objects. I'm attempting to destructure `country` from the `partner` array. It is a project requirement that `partner` be an *array* of objects, even though there should only ever be one partner country per obj.

```
arr = [
   { title: "Title A",
     desc: "Desc A",
     role: {role_desc: "Role Desc A", role_name: "Role A"},
     partner: [{country: "Brazil", region: "SA"}]
   },
   { title: "Title B",
     desc: "Desc B",
     role: {role_desc: "Role Desc B", role_name: "Role B"},
     partner: [{country: "US", region: "NA"}]
   }
]
```

I am able to populate a table with data for all fields except `partner`.

```
arr.map(
  ({ title, desc, role: {role_name}, partner: [{country}] }) => 
  ({ title, desc, role: {role_name}, partner: [{country}] })
);
```

I've referred to [Destructure object properties inside array for all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069301/destructure-object-properties-inside-array-for-all-elements) and [Destructuring an array of objects with es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187778/destructuring-an-array-of-objects-with-es6), and it looks like it is not possible to do this without transforming the data first.

Any help would be appreciated (and apologies for the dupe).

Comment: It's not very clear what your expected output is.

Comment: [`JS demo`](https://jsbin.com/yocatipefi/edit?js,console) i don't see any problem in destructuring here, please explain where is problem

Comment: `let [{ partner:[{ country }] }] = arr;` returns country "Brazil", not sure why you would want to do it this way tho...

Comment: Could you provide the JSON output/result, how should the transformation look like. It seems that there is a lot of unclarity regarding your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overlooking a very simple answer due to an equally simple error:

```
arr.map(
  ({ title, desc, role: {role_name}, partner}) => 
  ({ title, desc, role: {role_name}, partner: (partner[0] && partner[0].country) || 'Undefined' })
);
```

Every item in the array did not necessarily have a "country" property. For certain items, `partner` is just an empty array. The above fixed the issue.

I agree that it doesn't make sense to make `partner` an array if it will only ever contain one object. Client requirements, however.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use default value when you want to handle the case when partner is empty array,

```js
const arr = [{ title: "Title A",desc: "Desc A",role: {role_desc: "Role Desc A", role_name: "Role A"},partner: [{country: "Brazil", region: "SA"}]},{ title: "Title B",desc: "Desc B",role: {role_desc: "Role Desc B", role_name: "Role B"},partner: [{country: "US", region: "NA"}]},{ title: "Title C",desc: "Desc C",role: {role_desc: "Role Desc C", role_name: "Role C"},partner: []}]

const final = arr.map(
  ({ title, desc, role: {role_name}, partner}) => 
  ({ title, desc, role: {role_name}, partner:[ {country} = {country: undefined } ] })
);

console.log(final)
```

---

That being said we should keep our code as readable as possible, here it becomes so hard on eyes instead of trying to save one extra line, we should opt for making it more readable

```js
const arr = [{ title: "Title A",desc: "Desc A",role: {role_desc: "Role Desc A", role_name: "Role A"},partner: [{country: "Brazil", region: "SA"}]},{ title: "Title B",desc: "Desc B",role: {role_desc: "Role Desc B", role_name: "Role B"},partner: [{country: "US", region: "NA"}]},{ title: "Title C",desc: "Desc C",role: {role_desc: "Role Desc C", role_name: "Role C"},partner: []}]

const final = arr.map(
  ({ title, desc, role: {role_name}, partner}) => {
     let country = partner[0] && partner[0].country || undefined
    return { title, desc, role: {role_name}, partner:[ {country}] }
  }
);

console.log(final)
```